# Filter several columns in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 1 line and several columns (136).
The line can have 3 possible values (1,2,3).
I would like to filter only the columns which has value 3.

I tried this

```
data[data[1,]==3,]
```

but it returns a strange matrix

```
     INEP4 KEPL3 TRPL4 EZTC3 MYPK3 VLID3 MILS3 CGAS5 SMTO3 GOLL4
NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA.1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA.2     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: that would pull the rows where the first column was equal (exactly) to 3. And because of the behavior of "[" with NA values it would give all NA in the rows where the first column was NA as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to subset the columns of "data" that has '3' in its first row.  In that case,

```
 data[,data[1,]==3]
 #   V3 V6 V8 V9 V13 V14 V16
 #1  3  3  3  3   3   3   3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:3, 20*1, replace=TRUE), ncol=20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most unambiguous problem description I have ever seen but perhaps:

```
 data[ , grep("3", names(data))]  #any column name with a  "3" in it
```

Also possible that you want:

```
data[ data[[1]]==3 & !is.na(data[[1]]) , ] # only rows with first col == 3
```

Comment: Maybe. I thought it was rather unclear and didn't think your reading was the likely one.